# What are the two directions for $z$-axis in this paragraph?

Tags: reference-frames, coordinate-systems, vectors

> When we choose a coordinate system any two perpendicular lines may be chosen as $X$ and $Y$ axes. However, once $X$ and $Y$ axes are chosen, there are two possible choices of $Z$-axis. The $Z$-axis must be perpendicular to the $X-Y$ plane. But the positive direction of $Z$-axis may be defined in two ways. We choose the positive direction of $Z$-axis in such a way that $$\vec i \times \vec j = \vec k$$ Such a coordinate system is called a *right handed system*. In such a system $$\vec j \times \vec k = \vec i$$ and $$\vec k \times \vec i = \vec j$$ Of course $$\vec i \times \vec i = \vec j \times \vec j = \vec k \times \vec k = 0$$

How can there be two choices for $Z$-axis? I am not able to imagine it.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: I doesn't say there's more than one z-axis.  It says the *positive direction* of z can point in either of two directions.  You choose the one you think is best.  The one that points exactly opposite was the other choice. (Unless you chose poorly.)

Comment: Ok thanks . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by PaulPhy basically says everything, but I thought that this image would be a nice addition:

[image]

Starting from your text, the $XY$ (or $x_1 x_2$) Plane is already given. So there is only one choice for the $Z$ ($x_3$) axis as it must be perpendicular to both the $X$ and $Y$ axis.

The only thing we can choose is, as described in your textbook, the *direction* of the $Z$ axis, or "where its positive numbers are". If we choose to have its direction going "upwards" (this is more precisely described in the other answer as $\vec x \times \vec y = \vec z$ etc.), the vector $\vec v = \begin{pmatrix} 2\\3\\5 \end{pmatrix}$ is represented here by $\vec {OA}$.

If we were to choose the $Z$ axis in the other direction (the blue arrow would have to be at the other side), the same vector would be shown by what is here $\vec {OB}$.

Answer (score 2):

It means that you have a choice about which direction is positive in the $z$ direction. If you have a sheet of paper, you can draw a line orthogonal to the plane (piece of paper). You have a choice to make about if coming above the paper is negative or positive. It's largely arbitrary, but usually for cross products, we have decided that $\hat{x}\times\hat{y}= \hat{z}$ and that $\hat{y}\times\hat{x}= -\hat{z}$ and call this a right handed system. It is named this way because if you take your right hand, stick your fingers in the $x$ direction and curl them in the direction of the $y$ axis, the direction that you thumb points is the positive $z$ direction.